# Fast-RCNN as CNN feature extractor

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to use Fast-RCNN as CNN feature extractor for each of the final regions.

All I need to do is to get the index of the final regions out of all proposed regions, so that I can retrieve the corresponding features from the scores list (https://github.com/rbgirshick/fast-rcnn/blob/master/lib/fast_rcnn/test.py#L189) which I modified to contain the 4096-d fc7 features (for all proposed regions).

I have a feeling that it may turn out to be simple, yet I'm having a hard time figuring out a way to do it.

Comment: You will get more interest if you direct this question to statisticians http://stats.stackexchange.com